# Add a serial number to duplicate fields based another column grouped in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, unique, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

Column A is a Composite of student ID & Course number, column B is a name, I want to add a serial number for the course that resets by student.

This is what I have.

```
| Course     | Name        |
|:-----------|------------:|
| 107        |      James  |
| 107        |      James  |
| 108        |      James  |
| 108        |      James  |
| 109        |      James  |
| 109        |      James  |
| 233        |      Charley|
| 233        |      Charley|
| 256        |      Charley|
| 256        |      Charley|
| 311        |      Samuel |
| 311        |      Samuel |
| 344        |      Samuel |
| 344        |      Samuel |
```

This is what I would like.

```
| Course     | Name        | Count       |
|:-----------|------------:|------------:|
| 107        |      James  |      1      |
| 107        |      James  |      1      |
| 108        |      James  |      2      |
| 108        |      James  |      2      |
| 109        |      James  |      3      |
| 109        |      James  |      3      |
| 233        |      Charley|      1      |
| 233        |      Charley|      1      |
| 256        |      Charley|      2      |
| 256        |      Charley|      2      |
| 311        |      Samuel |      1      |
| 311        |      Samuel |      1      |
| 344        |      Samuel |      2      |
| 344        |      Samuel |      2      |
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A&B2:B, {UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A&B2:B, B2:B<>"")), 
 COUNTIFS(INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:B, B2:B<>"")),,2), 
          INDEX(UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:B, B2:B<>"")),,2), 
          ROW(INDIRECT("L2:L"&COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)+1)), 
     "<="&ROW(INDIRECT("L2:L"&COUNTUNIQUE(A2:A)+1)))}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]